# How to develop a Community Radio using Server-Client Model in JSP/php

Tags: jsp, networking, web-applications, client-server

I want to develop a web  application based on Server-Client model using JSP/php such that it supports streaming of audio files (only ".mp3" format). Basically server will read an audio file and broadcast it to all the connected clients and they will be able to listen to the audio.The application shall run on LAN. I know questions similar to this have been asked but I don't want the code, I would really appreciate if someone can suggest some reference from where I can read from or please describe a high level implementation for the same. Thanks in advance.